# What is de Difference between "At the beginning" and "At the outset"

Tags: expressions, sentence, phrase-meaning

I'm reading a book, and the book uses **"At the outset"** instead **"At the beginning"**.

I don't understand the difference between this two words, ¿When I need to use **At the outset**? ¿When I need to use **At the beginning**?

¿Or can I use both whenever I want?

Comment: In English we don't put an upside-down question mark at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: There's no significant difference. Check the dictionary for the meaning of *outset*, and it just means the beginning.

Comment: However, *outset* is generally only used for the beginning of something that exists in time. You wouldn't usually use it for physical objects.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you? What part of that is unclear to you?